# Compiling single file from Chromium

Tags: c++, compilation, codeql

I am trying to run codeql on Chromium among a few other open-source software, and I was wondering if it is possible to compile a single file from the full source code, because my machine takes a long time to compile such huge codebases.

For example, is it possible to compile the `media/filters/ffmpeg_video_decoder.cc` file only?

Comment: I am not sure how useful it would be to build a single file of a large library. You can't really use the object file without the other dependencies.

Comment: Run the compiler with all the appropriate command line arguments specifying the necessary include directories and any symbol definitions used to control conditional compiling that you want and you're done. If you want to link it into a binary you'll also need to compile any dependencies and include those as well.

Comment: one part of buidling the whole project is to compile this one file only.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling is not the issue. If you only compile one source file, it will be missing several functions that would be added to the final binary in the linker phase.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)

Only compiling one file will (most probably) not make a working binary, as you need a `main` function along with all the other code.

From a quick `CTRL-F` through the source code, a `main` function, which is critical for the program to run, is absent from the file you mentioned, so you definitely won't be able to make a working executable.

If you're making a `.lib` (library) file, it might work, although you're almost certainly going to run into undefined references, as the code is broken apart among many files.

Comment: My main goal is to check whether or not codeql can find a known vulnerability in a single file, in which case I don't really need the other functions to work, just a single function in said file to compile. Will that be possible?

Comment: It should be possible to build the single file. You may have to spend some time to figure out the proper command line arguments to the compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm I am quite new to C++. Do you have any recommendations on how to do that?